# Android: Using StartActivityFor Result

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I have a header with icon hidden, I have a adapter with a listview when I click the listview I go to a login screen using listener, when the login is successful is should come back to listview(adapter) and icon should get visible on header. i am sending intent as follows: http://pastebin.com/4SKnyjVX

below is onclick the login button

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    if(password.equals("guest")){
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
        setResult(1,returnIntent);     
        finish();
    } else {
        //----
    }

    finish();                  
}
```

how can i use onActivityResult to set a flag and use this flag in click listener, 
and also use it  to make the icon visible. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: When you say header, do you mean a view attached to the ListView using `setHeaderView()`? Or is it a standalone ViewGroup like LinearLayout placed at the top of your Activity?

Comment: @Ole yeah it is a standalone ViewGroup at top of activity common for all screens

Comment: Then check out the answer Enigma posted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your previous activity where you have listview with hidden icon in header, override the function onActivityResult() something like this -

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    boolean success = data.getBooleanExtra("result", false);
    if(success) {
        hiddenIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        showDialog("Error");
   }
}
```

And I've changed your onClick this way

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        if(password.equals("guest")){
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", true);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);     
        } 
        else {
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", false);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        }

        finish();                  
    }
```

Comment: iam calling this login screen from a listener, so do i need to place this onactivityresult() in listener or adapter?

Comment: onActivityResult should be in your Activity

Comment: but that activity alreay has one more oonActivityResult

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent)`:

- `requestCode` is the integer that you originally passed as the second parameter to `startActivityForResult()`. You should check this matches your original request, in case you have multiple requests you have to differentiate between.
- `resultCode` and `resultIntent` is the integer and intent you pass to `setResult()` in your code above.

So your method should look something like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
    if (requestCode == 1) { // original request
        if (resultCode == 1) { // success
            String result = resultIntent.getStringExtra("result");
            // Login successful, update your model and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle basket=data.getExtras();
        String s=basket.getString("result");
        //Your Code Here
    }
}
```

This will be helpful